# Saving layer as shapefile using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, vector-layer, save, writers

Using QGIS 3.4.4, I'm trying to save a layer as shapefile with the following code:

```py
import os
import qgis.core

working_folder = r'C:\myFolder'
fc_Prospect = os.path.join(working_folder, Equipment.gdb|layername=Prospect) 
layer1 = QgsVectorLayer(fc_Prospect, 'Prospect', 'ogr')
       
path = r'C:\myFolder\test.shp'
_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer1,path,'utf-8','ESRI Shapefile')
```

However, I am getting this error:

> TypeError: QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(): arguments did
> not match any overloaded call:
> overload 1: argument 4 has unexpected
> type 'str'
> overload 2: argument 4 has unexpected type 'str'
> overload 3: argument 3 has unexpected type 'str'

I am quite new with python, so I am not sure what this error means. I've been checking documentation at https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorFileWriter.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat, but it didn't really help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Vector/QgsVectorFileWriter.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat) suggests that it is expecting these parameters:

> Parameters:
>
> layer – layer to write
>
> fileName – file name to write to
>
> fileEncoding – encoding to use
>
> destCRS – CRS to reproject exported geometries to, or  invalid CRS for no reprojection
>
> driverName – OGR driver to use
>
> onlySelected – write only selected features of layer
>
> errorMessage – pointer to buffer fo error message
>
> datasourceOptions – list of OGR data source creation options
>
> layerOptions – list of OGR layer creation options
>
> skipAttributeCreation – only write geometries
>
> newFilename – QString pointer which will contain the new file name created (in case
>    it is different to fileName).
>
> symbologyExport – symbology to export
>
> symbologyScale – scale of symbology
>
> filterExtent – if not a null pointer, only features intersecting the extent will be saved (added in QGIS 2.4)
>
> overrideGeometryType – set to a valid geometry type to
>   override the default geometry type for the layer. This paramet

So your error says it is expecting the 4th parameter to be a CRS not a string.

I suspect that means you should write your call as:

```
_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer1,path,'utf-8',driverName='ESRI Shapefile')
```

Comment: I've tested what you suggest and it works, although it throws an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QgsVectorLayer has been deleted.
Any ideas what that means?

Comment: beyond me I'm afraid